# data.table - split data.table into elements of a lists using ~ var|factor - cast / dcast

Tags: r, casting, data.table, dcast

I have a large `data.table` which I am using for subsequent analysis on different levels of the data. In order to avoid repetitive code, I would like to break my `data.table` into smaller chunks and save them as (elements of) lists. Couple of days ago I have seen a post where something like this was used:

```
setDT(mtcars)
names(mtcars)
combi <- dcast(mtcars[,.(carb, gear, mpg, cyl, vs)], cyl + gear ~ vs|cyl)
```

This resulted in a separate (wide) data.table containing `cyl`, `gear`, `vs` - separately for year `cyl`. The emphasis is on saving separate `data.table` for every cyl, not necessarily on wide table (I believe the post used `cast` or `dcast` to achieve the desired results)

However, I cannot find the post anywhere and also cannot find any documentation about similar manipulations. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the expected output `split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shows how to get datatables for each level of cyl into a list - if you want to write them to a .txt file etc. then just alter that section to be fwrite(...). Note it is working through in the order that cyl has in the data (i = 1 is when cyl = 6, i = 2 is when cyl = 4...):

```
dtCars <- data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)
carsList <- list()
for(i in 1:length(dtCars[,unique(cyl)])){
  carsList[[i]] <- dtCars[cyl == unique(cyl)[i]]
}
```